# bitset with scoped enums doesn't compile

Tags: c++, templates, enums, bitset

I am trying to use a `std::bitset` with an `enum` but I am getting a compilation error saying

template argument 1 is invalid

Funny thing is that when I use any of the enumerated value without the enumeration scope it works fine.

Do you know why?

Below the code

```
   enum MyTypes {
     Alpha  = 1,
     Beta  = 2,
     Gamma = 3
   };


   std::bitset<MyTypes::Alpha> bitset_wrong; // It doesn't compile.
   std::bitset<Alpha >         bitset_good;  // It works.
```

Comment: You need to compile with at least `-std=c++11` in order to use C++11 features.

Comment: @PaulR: thank unfortunately I don't have it available so I need to remove the scope manually. Do you know the reason behind that error? I am very interested in knowing why compiler is complaining about that innocent template.

Comment: Does `enum struct MyTypes{...}` work as a scoped enumerator? I'm not sure if unscoped enumerators support qualified names by default, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum : _Each enumerator becomes a named constant of the enumeration's type (that is, name), visible in the enclosing scope..._

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile: prior to C++11 you could only use a class name or namespace to qualify an identifier like this. `MyTypes` is neither, so it would be an error to try and use it as a qualifier.

Comment: Proper spelling of α is alpha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have an old compiler that does not support specifying qualified names with unscoped enumerators.

Update your compiler.:)

The code you showed is a valid code according to the C++ 2011 Standard.

Here is a quote from the C++ Standard with an example (7.2 Enumeration declarations)

> 11 Each enum-name and each unscoped enumerator is declared in the
>   scope that immediately contains the enum-specifier. Each scoped
>   enumerator is declared in the scope of the enumeration. These names
>   obey the scope rules defined for all names in (3.3) and (3.4).

[ Example:

```
enum direction { left=’l’, right=’r’ };
void g() {
direction d; // OK
d = left; // OK
d = direction::right; // OK
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't have C++11 that I can't use. Do you know the reason behind that error?

Comment: @Abruzzo Forte e Gentile  AFAIK the old C++ 2003 Standard deos not allow to use qualified names for enumerators.